# How do I run a Jenkins Pipeline stage only on specifically matched branch names?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'd like to only run a stage in a Jenkins pipeline (`Jenkinsfile`) if the branch matches a specific regular expression (regex).

Something like:

```
pipeline {
...
stages {
  stage('Test') {
    when {
        // pseudo code
        branch name == regex(/^foo.*bar/)
    }
  }
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is by using the `expression` section combined with the `~==` operator (which returns a boolean).

```
def branch_name = "${BRANCH_NAME}"
pipeline {
...
stages {
  stage('Test') {
    when {
        expression {
            // use !(expr) to negate something, || for or, && for and
            return branch_name =~ /^foo.*bar/

        }
    }
  }
}
...
}
```

Comment: isn't it the `==~` operator and is that what is meant to be shown in the answer code?

Comment: `Find operator` vs. `Match operator`, right? http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_match_operator